# Can I remap an ECU using CAN bus?

Tags: arduino, protocols, microcontroller, can-bus

I am thinking to use something like this to connect an Arduino to a motorbike ECU: http://www.skpang.co.uk/catalog/arduino-canbus-shield-with-usd-card-holder-p-706.html

I never do something like this, and I would know if using CAN bus I can only read some diagnostic parameter in the ECU or if I can also remap some ECU parameters.

Can you help me to understand this thing?

Comment: Probaly better asked on EE.SE  Whether ECU parameters can be remapped depends only on ECU (the bus itself is bidirectional), so see your ECU documentation for that.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Via CAN you can primarily read messages transferred between different control modules in the vehicle. Many of these messages conform to a manufacturer-independent standard and can be taken as well-known or documented.

However, there are also manufacturer-specific messages which are usually not documented for access by the public. Messages controlling the configuration of the ECU and other modules are most likely of this kind, regarded as private to the manufacturer.

Therefore, messages for configuration of the control modules will mostly only be documented by someone who figured them out via reverse-engineering.

Reading and interpreting messages sent regularily on the bus should not be too difficult, as far as the messages are documented or can be analyzed easily. Those configuration messages will be hard to get hold of, probably impossible given hobbyist's means and tools.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not unless you know the specific diagnostic protocol implementation for this bike (usually KWP2000 or UDS), which may or may not support the ECU re flashing.

CAN is just the communication protocol. To do so, you would need to know the seed generation algorithm for security sessions access and then be able to send new data to the ECU. If you had all this information, you would then be able to reflash or remap the ECU. Why would you want to do this anyway?